# SQL - Updating a column from another table while concatenating the related record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Using SQL, how would I go about updating a column on 1 table, with data from a related/joined table using all the records found, concatenated together? Rather than just updating it based on a specific record, I want to concatenate the fields together and use that for the update.

Table 1

```
ID|Col1|Col2
1|Hello|Hello2
2|HelloHello|HelloHello2
```

Table 2

```
ParentID|Tbl2Col1|Tbl2Col2
1|Value1|Value2
1|Value1|Value2
1|Value1|Value2
2|Value2|Value3
```

I want to update Table 1, ID 1, Col2 value to be the concatenated values of all the Table 2 Tbl2Col2 child records based on the Table2.ParentID = Table1.ID.

So Table 1 would then look like this when done:

```
ID|Col1|Col2
1|Hello|Value2, Value2, Value2
2|HelloHello|HelloHello2
```

ID 1, Col2 is now set to each of the values found from Table 2, Tbl2Col2 column.

**Updated 2/17/20**
I tried building this out via [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/80898/7) and ran into trouble with the UPDATE statement. I'm able to build out the SELECT query, but I receive an error when I perform the UPDATE: *Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.*

It's actually a bit more complicated too, I need to have Incident.JournalDescriptions end up looking like: Journal.CreatedDateTime + '\n' Journal.Description.

Basically, combine the CreatedDateTime and Description for each of the related Journal records and update the Incident.JournalDescriptions field.

Here's the table structure and queries I've tried:

```
CREATE TABLE Incident
    ([RecID] varchar(42), [JournalDescriptions] varchar(max))
;
CREATE TABLE Journal
    ([ParentRecID] varchar(42), [Description] varchar(max), [CreatedDateTime] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Incident
    ([RecID], [JournalDescriptions])
VALUES
    ('1', ''),
    ('2', '')
;

INSERT INTO Journal
    ([ParentRecID], [Description], [CreatedDateTime])
VALUES
    ('1', 'My Journal Description 1', Getdate()+1),
    ('1', 'My Journal Description 2', Getdate()+2),
    ('2', 'My Journal Description 3', Getdate()+3)
;

-- UPDATE STATEMENT ERRORS: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
UPDATE Incident
SET JournalDescriptions = (SELECT
  I.RecID,
  I.JournalDescriptions,
  STRING_AGG(J.Description, '<br />') RegDates,
  STRING_AGG(J.CreatedDateTime, '<br />') WaitListDates
FROM
  Incident AS I
  JOIN Journal AS J
  ON I.RecID = J.ParentRecID
GROUP BY I.RecID, I.JournalDescriptions);
WHERE Incident.RecID = '1'

-- SELECT STATEMENT WORKS
SELECT
  I.RecID,
  I.JournalDescriptions,
  STRING_AGG(J.Description, '<br />') RegDates,
  STRING_AGG(J.CreatedDateTime, '<br />') WaitListDates
FROM
  Incident AS I
  JOIN Journal AS J
  ON I.RecID = J.ParentRecID
GROUP BY I.RecID, I.JournalDescriptions
```

**Update #2 2/17/20**

I was able to get this UPDATE query to work for a SINGLE row only, when I specify the RecID in both the inner/outer clauses.

```
UPDATE Incident
SET JournalDescriptions = (SELECT
 STRING_AGG(J.Description + CONVERT(varchar, J.CreatedDateTime), '<br />') AS Updated
FROM
  Incident AS I
  JOIN Journal AS J
  ON I.RecID = J.ParentRecID and I.RecID = '1'
GROUP BY I.RecID)
WHERE Incident.RecID = '1';

SELECT RecID,JournalDescriptions FROM Incident;
```

Comment: it would be useful to know your database, there are different ways to write the query depending on the engine you are using. In Oracle LISTAGG, on mysql GROUP_CONCAT...

Comment: Wouldn't `ID 2` `Col2` be `Value3` in the final result table? Based on your description.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using,

Comment: Thanks, I updated the tags to reflect Microsoft SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of string concatenation in your database, but the idea is:

```
update table1
    set col2 = (select string_agg(t2.Tbl2Col2, ',')
                from table2 t2
                where t2.ParentId = table1.id
               );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I'll give this a try and see if I can get it working.

Comment: I actually receive an error that string_agg is not available. Running SQL Server 2014. Error: string_agg is not a recognized built-in function

Comment: I'm still trying to find a solution that works in SQL 2014, however, messing around in 2017 I was able to get the SELECT to work, but not actually the UPDATE. I just updated my original question to include a better example of the tables using the string_add example provided by Gordon.

Comment: This code almost works, it groups all the Descriptions together rather than puts the Date near the related Description, which is what is intended. SELECT
  STRING_AGG(J.Description, '<br />') + STRING_AGG(J.CreatedDateTime, '<br />') AS Updated
FROM
  Incident AS I
  JOIN Journal AS J
  ON I.RecID = J.ParentRecID
GROUP BY I.RecID

Comment: My latest example/update in the OP shows it working/updating for a single record, RecID = '1' - I can't get it to run for all records though...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help/direction.

The actual solution is:

```
UPDATE TOP (1000)
       Incident
SET
       AllJournals = STUFF((
    SELECT 'Created: ' + CONVERT(varchar, CreatedDateTime) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Description: ' + Description + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
              FROM Journal
              WHERE ParentRecID = RecID
              ORDER BY CreatedDateTime ASC
              FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 0, ''),
       Archived = 1
FROM
       Incident I
WHERE
       CreatedDateTime BETWEEN @Start_Date and @End_Date AND
       Archived != 1
       AND NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT NULL
              FROM ArchiveDB.dbo.Incident I2
              WHERE I2.RecID = I.RecID
       );
```

This code will combine data from the related Journal table based on the RecID column matching. It also only executes the UPDATE when the update has not already happened.